# Correct way to perform expensive per-worker setup

Tags: locust

What's the correct / best way to perform costly per-process initialisation when using multiple workers, ensuring the workers can correctly communicate with the master?

As part of a custom `locustfile.py` I need to download a large dataset from a URL and load into memory to generate GET request parameters (download time ~60s; load time  takes ~5s). For a single-process locust setup I have used the `init` event to perform this, and that works fine. However when running with multiple workers (`--processes=N`) I've run into a few issues with simply using the `init` event:

**Attempt 1**: As `init` is fired once per process, using that event for all workers results in downloading the same files from all processes, which is inefficient and causes problems with files overwriting each other.

**Attempt 2**: Based on the [`test_data_management.py` example](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/test_data_management.py), I tried having master / local runner downloading via `init`, but deferring the loading (only from disk, re-using the already-downloaded files) until `on_start`:

```py
@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, WorkerRunner):
        # Download (if not exists in local files), read and load
        # into environment.dataset
        setup_dataset(environment)
...
@events.test_start.add_listener
def setup_worker_dataset(environment, **_kwargs):
    if isinstance(environment.runner, WorkerRunner):
        # Make the Dataset available for WorkerRunners (non-Worker will have
        # already downloaded the dataset via on_locust_init).
        setup_dataset(environment, skip_download_and_populate=True)
```

This seems to work ok if `setup_worker_dataset()` is quick (less than 1s), however for larger datasets it can take longer, and I see problems with the master / worker communication, and load generation terminates:

```
locust-swarm-0-f008c40/INFO/locust.runners: Worker locust-swarm-0-xxx failed to send heartbeat, setting state to missing.
locust-swarm-0-f008c40/INFO/locust.runners: Worker locust-swarm-0-yyy failed to send heartbeat, setting state to missing.
locust-swarm-0-f008c40/INFO/locust.runners: The last worker went missing, stopping test.
```

(Of note setup_dataload() performs blocking / CPU-heavy work, so I expect it's preventing the gevent event loop from running)

Essentially I need a "safe place" to perform some CPU-heavy work at the process/environment level before the User objects start running tasks.

Comment: For similar problem, I download the files in another gevent job that i spawn in init method fixing the missing worker thing.

Comment: With approach 2 you can increase the wait time before a worker is considered to be missing. Check runners.py (just import it into your locustfile and overwrite the constant)